# Deploy .war file to Liferay using only web based UI

Tags: liferay

Is it possible to deploy a .war file in Liferay 6.1 without using any separate tomcat connections? I am able to access Liferay's web UI. I am not able to access the server with any other 3rd party software, nor I do not know how to do it.

The Liferay portal in question is Liferay Portal Enterprise Edition 6.1.20 EE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install from Liferay marketplace the "private installer portlet" that allows you to upload and deploy the war from the control panel.

[Downlaod from here](https://www.liferay.com/it/marketplace/-/mp/application/15473837)

Comment: in case somebody with CE comes along and finds this question/answer, find the CE version of this plugin here: https://www.liferay.com/it/marketplace/-/mp/application/15474932